# Matrix Reloaded - How did the message from the Oracle get out of the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In The Matrix Reloaded, there's a scene where Bane (the one who gets taken over by Smith) and some other guy (don't remember his name) are running from the Agents with a message from the Oracle in an envelope.  Bane hands the envelope to the other guy and says "The only thing that matters is this".  The other guys puts it in his pocket and then jacks out of the Matrix.  Later on, the message from the Oracle is handed to Neo.  This seems to imply that the item in his pocket was taken with him to the real world when he left the Matrix.  Obviously, this is absurd.  So how did the message get out?

**Note that I'm looking for an in-universe explanation for this and not wild speculation**

Comment: Real->Construct+Operator+real computer->Matrix. Matrix->Construct+Operator+real computer->Real.

Comment: should be noted that the last transmission of the Osiris that reports the machine attack also came from the Matrix from a PO box. It starts in the Animatrix and continues in Enter the Matrix, landing in Reloaded.

Comment: the other guy is called Malachi, he is from Ballard's ship. (Ballard is the black guy helping out Morpheus with the 36 hours; he meets the Oracle for the message). They together with Bane are crew on a ship what is apparently called Caduceus (albeit I yet to dig the source of this information up as I can't currently remember). Malachi is not named in Reloaded by any character, but text sources mention him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely explanation that comes to mind is a intermediary virtual environment similar to where Neo and Trinity loaded up on guns prior to rescuing Morpheus in the first movie.

In such a location the Operator should be able to download the message and transcribe it onto something real.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like that too, but I wanted to see what others thought.  I know that, in the first movie, they mention their loading program.  It's not hard to imagine that they can "save" the items on their digital self-image to a similar program and load the data onto a physical format later.

Comment: When they hand the letter to Neo, as I recall they say something about downloading message from the Oracle.

Comment: Or he simply push the Print Screen button, and paste into Gimp or something similar.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas That's Zimp, the Zion Image Manipulation Program